# Facing Issue While "Add a new Promotion" in Targeting

Tags: dxa, fredhopper, web8.5

After given a name for Add a new Promotion, where --> context panel --> pages, I clicked on adding a new page where I am getting the below error

> "Error processing response stream. Server failed with following message: Unable to get a list of Attributes. Please refer to the SmartTarget log files for more information."

But still I able to add a page, where --> context panel --> page regions. When I clicked on Page Regions, I am getting the below error with no output in the right side panel of page regions.

> "Error processing response stream. Server failed with following message: Unable to get a list of Trigger Types, please refer to the SmartTarget log files for more information"

Any configuration needs to be done? (or) do I left out anything while configuring?

Comment: the error message says 'Please refer to the SmartTarget log files for more information'. Do you see anything useful in these logs ?

Comment: Are you using Smart target with Web 8 or with Tridion 2013?
Where is the fredhopper installed? Is it on cloud or on premise?
Which operating system is being used for fredhopper? Windows or Linux?
Are you using some custom triggers in SmartTarget?
Triggers types not loading means some configuration is still missing.
If you are using custom trigger type then please check your smarttarget_conf.xml file. 
You have to register prefix for the custom trigger type in <AmbientData> section in smarttarget_conf.xml file.
Also please check you business.xml is in place.

Comment: @HaraldHoffelinck : This is what my log states"DEBUG TriggerTypesHelper - Created new instance of TriggerTypeProvider implementation class: com.tridion.smarttarget.query.TriggerTypeProviderImpl"

Comment: @Sumit: Answers for your questions, Web 8.5, Server System, not in cloud, Windows Server 2016, Windows, No. may i know what is business.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Are your Fredhopper Index & Query servers actually running?

You check trigger-types directly from Fredhopper with the following URL:

```
http://<your_ip_address>:<port>/fredhopper/config/trigger-types
```

Does this give you a response?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the SmartTarget Management capability in your discovery service configuration. Check What your SmartTargetManagement.svc returning for the following query,

http://localhost:8093/management.svc/TriggerTypes (It may be little trickier to query the service if OAuth is enabled in your microservice, as we need to set the credentials in the request headers)

If there are any errors, change the log level to Debug to get detailed information about the error

Also, in the Fredhopper installation directory, check whether you have the trigger-types.xml file available
C:{fredhopper-installation}\data\instances{instance-name}\config\trigger-types.xml

Hope this helps

Comment: "Error processing response stream. Server failed with following message:
Unable to get a list of Trigger Types, please refer to the SmartTarget log files for more information" is what the error I am getting now. I have checked the logs nothing defined specific. Verified the trigger-types.xml and it is fine.